# Why user.is_authenticated not working? django, LoginRequiredMixin

Tags: python, django

I'm logged in.  why display `NOT LOGIN!` in html?

**VIEWS**
​

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
​
class UserHomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'users/users_index.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    context_object_name = 'user'
​
    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

​
**HTML**
​

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
LOGIN!
{% else %}
NOT LOGIN!
{% endif %}
```

**setting.py**

```
LOGIN_URL = '/users/login/'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}